# SpringMVC-Aspectj integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I want to configure spring AOP into my Spring MVC project:
**Below is the code:**

package com.samik.aspect;

```
    import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Aspect
    public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("HomeGetter()")
    public void LoggingAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        System.out.println("Logger Advice called for Home Request");
        System.out.println(joinPoint.toString());
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(protected ModelAndView getHomePage())")
    public void HomeGetter(){}
    }
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Main.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView getHomePage(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("content/home/Home");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

**Added the below code in dispatcher servlet:**

```
<bean id = "loggingAspect" class = "com.samik.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name='loggingAspect' />
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

Not getting the error, Please help. Looked into the internet, this is what the solution is proposed.
Please revert if i am missing anything?

Comment: Error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager'
: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

warning no match for this type name: ModelAndView [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Answer (score 0):

The error message `ModelAndView [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]` means that in your pointcut you use a type name which does not exist (or is not fully qualified). It should help to change the pointcut to:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(protected org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView getHomePage())")
```